# Sending and receiving fax via GSM Network in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, fax, gsm

How can I send and receive faxes in Ubuntu using a GSM Network?

Which hardware would you suggest? Which fax client? Would this work easily or is it complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a GSM module and some PBX program, like Asterisk to do that (you can also create a PBX software using module's API). Take a look at this: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/GSM and find for "GSM PCI-Express Module" on google. Im sure you will find something on Pika Technologies or Khomp.

Answer (score 3):

I was also wondering about this; I just need to send fax from Linux via bluetooth phone, though - not receive them. So I thought I'd jot down my notes.

Turns out, there's a program `/usr/bin/fax` - in Ubuntu, it's installed via `sudo apt-get install efax` (which is kinda inconvenient for online searches, as "eFax" is also the name of a well-know commercial service website... (and "fax" in itself is bound to get you many poor search results)).

I finally found this thread that seem to talk about exactly this thing, though; and here it is:

[sending faxes with t610 - gmane.comp.kde.devel.bluetooth / mailinglist for development of KDE utilities for bluetooth](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.kde.devel.bluetooth/25)

> > Actually you can use
> >
> > ```
> >  rfcomm bind /dev/frcomm0 <phone-bluetooth-address>
> > ```
> >
> > to bind the bluetooth device to /dev/rfcomm0. You can then use this device
> >     as a modem, e.g sending AT commands etc.
> >     ...
> >     A[s] I have a prepaid card, I can not send facsimiles, so consider this also, 
> >     wheter your provider allows you to send fax papers ;-) ...
>
> Hehe, I also had a long conversation with the hotline of my operator just a 
>   minute ago. For some reason I had to dial the fax number without 
>   international prefix (+49..).
>   ...
>   Well, this is my result - still problems with permissions, but it works.
>   efax also complained a lot about some non-existing lock file at first and I 
>   had to create some strange directories first.
>
> ```
> $ sudo /usr/bin/fax NAME='fred' DEV=rfcomm0 PAGE=a4 FROM='' send  
> '089********' '/tmp/kde-fred/kdeprint_mRL9Bbit'
> Password:
> /tmp/kde-fred/kdeprint_mRL9Bbit.nnn is up-to-date
> efax: Wed May 12 16:16:30 2004 efax v 0.9a-001114 Copyright 1999 Ed Casas
> efax: 16:32 opened /dev/rfcomm0
> efax: 16:33 using Nokia 3650 Nokia Nokia 3650 V 3.16 in class 2.0
> efax: 16:34 dialing T0891488297533
> efax: 16:49 remote ID -> "   +49 89 ********"
> efax: 16:49 connected
> efax: 16:56 session 196lpi  9600bps 8.5"/215mm  any   1D    -     -  0ms
> efax: 16:56 header:[2004/05/12 16:16  fred p. 1/2]
> efax: 17:49 sent 20+2292 lines, 52762+0 bytes, 53 s  7964 bps
> efax: 17:49 sent -> /tmp/kde-fred/kdeprint_mRL9Bbit.001
> efax: 17:50 header:[2004/05/12 16:16  fred p. 2/2]
> efax: 18:13 sent 20+2292 lines, 17649+0 bytes, 23 s  6138 bps
> efax: 18:13 sent -> /tmp/kde-fred/kdeprint_mRL9Bbit.002
> efax: 18:13 done, returning 0 (success)
> ```
>
> But the quality of faxes really sucks badly. I still prefer a pdf via email ;)

So, apparently it can be done from the command line - but only if your mobile operator has that service for your subscription, I guess...