# Fax from Mac OS X 10.6 via bluetooth phone?

Tags: mac, operating-systems, xorg, bluetooth, fax

I have my MacBook Pro with Mac OS X 10.6.8 set up to connect via Bluetooth to my Samsung Galaxy SII phone for file sharing and it works fine.

Now, I am wondering if there is a way to use my phone as a bluetooth fax modem that my Mac can connect to and send faxes??? If so, how?

I.e. I select a document and specify a destination fax number on my Mac, and my Bluetooth phone will take care of the actually dialling and faxing.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Not exactly for Mac - but you may want to check my post in [ubuntu - Sending and receiving fax via GSM Network in Linux - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/168776/sending-and-receiving-fax-via-gsm-network-in-linux/716307#716307), which documents some stuff I've found about sending fax via bluetooth phone; maybe it helps.